# jquery - jsonp overwrite callback get parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

I'm writing a dynamic js that should send a request to an action, that is defined in the href attribute in a link.

The link look like that:

```
  <a href="module/action?callback=MyCallback">show something</a>
```

As you can see the link has a get param named callback. That is defined, because the request method should be as generic as possible and the element should know by itself, what it has to do with the response.

Now i send the request with jquery ajax function to the action, looking like that:

```
jQuery('#mylink').live("click", function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType:"jsonp",
      error: ErrorHandler.catchXhrError,
      url: jQuery('#mylink').attr('href');
    });
});
```

That works very well, in principle. But my problem is, that jquery defines its own callback get param and i don't know, how i can tell the method, that the callback param in my links href is the right one and the request-uri is looking like that:

```
  http:/example.com/module/action?callback=MyCallback&callback=jsonp1279196981233
```

The only way out i see, is to define my own callback-param named mycallback and interpret mycallback in the action instead of callback:

```
<a href="module/action?callback=MyCallback">show something</a>
```

But i don't like this solution, because my request uri has a param that will not be used:

```
  http:/example.com/module/action?mycallback=MyCallback&callback=jsonp1279196981233
```

Please attend, that i could not define the name of the callback method inside the ajax method

```
jQuery('#mylink').live("click", function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType:"jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: 'MyCallback',
      error: ErrorHandler.catchXhrError,
      url: jQuery('#mylink').attr('href');
    });
});
```

because the send Method should be generic and will be used across our whole side and the response has to be processed in many different ways by different js methods.

Hope i could describe my problem sufficiently and would be happy about any help.

Comment: `callback` is not just for the client. The server has an equal say in what the callback parameter should be named. For example, YQL expects a param named `"_callback"`. If you do not control this parameter on the server side, then just let the url include the param name as part of its attributes. `<a href="http://example.com" data-callback="theCallback" />`. Doesn't get more generic than this. Fallback to a default key `"callback"`, if none specified.

Comment: Also, you can't send two `callback` params and expect all servers to behave the same. Some might pick up the first one, others might pickup the second one. YQL, again, for example, always uses the first `callback` param if there are multiple. So it's not about redundancy but more about unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `jQuery.ajax` version but not hardcode the callback name. Instead parse the href attribute and extract the name of the callback to use..

and here is the parsing..

```
jQuery('#mylink').live("click", function() {
    var href = jQuery('#mylink').attr('href');

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType:"jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: href.match(/([?&]callback[a-zA-Z0-9=]+)/)[0].split('=')[1],
      error: ErrorHandler.catchXhrError,
      url: href;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/ ?

Comment: Yes i did, but i didn't want to insert an extra lib for that. Thought i could resolve the problem by myself. I tried the solution from Gaby below and parse the callback param from the href. works well...

Comment: Glad you found a way out of this :)